# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que la base de datos actualice automáticamente los ID de los registros de una tabla después de eliminar un registro?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, update

Tengo una aplicación web en PHP con una base de datos en sql en phpmyadmin.

Quiero que al momento de eliminar un registro los ID de los registros que están después del registro que elimine se actualicen automáticamente.

Por ejemplo tengo la siguiente tabla:

| id_persona | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos |
| 2 | Juan |
| 3 | Mario |
| 4 | Diego |

Si tomo de ejemplo que quiero eliminar el segundo registro la tabla me quedaría así:

| id_persona | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos |
| 3 | Mario |
| 4 | Diego |

Los id de los registros siguientes al registro que eliminé siguen igual y yo quiero que se actualicen para que queden de esta manera:

| id_persona | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos |
| 2 | Mario |
| 3 | Diego |

Mejor dicho quiero los registros siguientes resten el ID que se eliminó.

Sería de gran ayuda un aporte a mi problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: No deberías hacer eso. Imagina que otra tabla dependiera de esta. Le cambiarías la referencias del saldo a pagar, o de materias a cursar, de consultorio clínico a los usuarios. Si es una sola tabla no habría tanto drama, pero cuando hay más tablas involucradas te meterás en grandes problemas. Acostúmbrate a ver esos "huecos" en la columna autoincremental. Incluso es normal que la propia BD se salte números, por ejemplo cuando le haces rollback a una transacción y luego intentas guardar otro registro.

Comment: No es recomendable cambiar los ´id´ de una tabla.  Pero si es meramente educativo.  Agrega el código que tienes a tu pregunta, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con lo que apuntan los compañeros.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con los otros. Si quieres números consecutivos, siempre puedes hacer `select row_number() over (order by id_persona) as num, nombre from mytable`.

Comment: ¿Que DBMS estás usando? Siempre pone la etiqueta de tu DBMS en preguntas de SQL, así que sabemos el dialecto de SQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner En la pregunta menciona phpmyadmin, por lo que está trabajando con MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Te respondo aunque no hayas aportado el código de tus pruebas porque la respuesta no la encontrarás en la dirección que buscas.

Como te han indicado muy acertadamente en los comentarios, no es conveniente modificar los autonuméricos y no pasa nada porque, por lo que sea, aparezcan huecos y la numeración no sea consecutiva, su función es únicamente la de que no haya duplicados.

Lo que no tiene nada que ver con que necesites numerar tus registros consecutivamente, y para eso tendrás que crearte un nuevo campo `n_orden`, por ejemplo, que haga esta función:

```
ALTER TABLE personas
  ADD n_orden int AFTER id_persona;
```

Para cumplimentarlo, tienes que hacer uso de variables como la `@i` que yo utilizaré:

```
set @i:=0;
UPDATE personas JOIN (
    SELECT id_persona,@i:=@i+1 orden
      FROM personas
      ORDER BY id_persona
  ) c1 USING(id_persona)
  set n_orden=orden;
```

Consulta que, tras un `UPDATE` combinado con `JOIN`, te dejará la tabla en este estado:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
| id_persona | n_orden | Nombre |
+------------+---------+--------+
|          1 |       1 | Carlos |
|          2 |       2 | Juan   |
|          3 |       3 | Mario  |
|          4 |       4 | Diego  |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

Cuando borres cualquier registro con:

```
DELETE FROM personas
  WHERE id_persona=2;
```

Ejecutando de nuevo el script, obtendrás:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
| id_persona | n_orden | Nombre |
+------------+---------+--------+
|          1 |       1 | Carlos |
|          3 |       2 | Mario  |
|          4 |       3 | Diego  |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

Esto resultará muy útil si a cada persona le quieres asignar un estante o algo similar. Si no quieres que se modifiquen los números ya asignados, puedes jugar con `c1` para que rellene esos huecos al insertar un nuevo registro. Supongamos que, justo tras eliminar a Juan, añades a Ricardo y a Pedro:

```
INSERT INTO personas (Nombre) VALUES
  ('Ricardo'),('Pedro');
```

Quedándote la tabla así:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| id_persona | n_orden | Nombre  |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |       1 | Carlos  |
|          3 |       3 | Mario   |
|          4 |       4 | Diego   |
|          5 |    NULL | Ricardo |
|          6 |    NULL | Pedro   |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Y no quieres modificar el `n_orden` de Mario y Diego, pero tampoco quieres huecos. Pues tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
set @i:=0,@j:=0,@k:=0;
UPDATE personas JOIN (
    SELECT *
      FROM (
        SELECT id_persona,@k:=@k+1 id
          FROM personas
          WHERE n_orden IS NULL
      ) c2 JOIN (
        SELECT n_orden,@j:=@j+1 id
          FROM personas p
          RIGHT JOIN (
            SELECT @i:=@i+1 n_orden
              FROM personas
          ) c1 USING(n_orden)
          WHERE id_persona IS NULL
      ) c3 USING(id)
  ) c4 USING(id_persona)
  set personas.n_orden=c4.n_orden;
```

Impresiona un poco, pero no tienes más que seguir las subconsultas para ver qué hace: crea una serie consecutiva, busca los huecos, numera éstos y los registros huérfanos y los combina por ese mismo `id` y actualiza finalmente el número de orden. Después de todo eso tu tabla quedará así:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| id_persona | n_orden | Nombre  |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |       1 | Carlos  |
|          3 |       3 | Mario   |
|          4 |       4 | Diego   |
|          5 |       2 | Ricardo |
|          6 |       5 | Pedro   |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Y, reordenándola un poco, así:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| id_persona | n_orden | Nombre  |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |       1 | Carlos  |
|          5 |       2 | Ricardo |
|          3 |       3 | Mario   |
|          4 |       4 | Diego   |
|          6 |       5 | Pedro   |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Espero que haya resuelto el problema que tuvieras. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Aporto el dataset de partida:

```
CREATE TABLE personas(
  id_persona int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Nombre varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO personas (Nombre) VALUES
('Carlos'),
('Juan'),
('Mario'),
('Diego');
```