# rellenar campo de texto con letras fijas y números variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

En mi bbdd tengo una tabla que guarda un campo llamado code y me gustaría que estuviera compuesto de dos letras fijas y cuatro números que pudiera yo introducirlos o que se introdujeran ascendentemente al crear un registro en la tabla.
En phpmyadmin el campo es de tipo CHAR de seis caracteres de longitud.
Sería, más o menos, así: PR0001
En el formulario tengo esto:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="product-code" placeholder="Código de producto" minlength="6" maxlength="6">
```

Comment: Con la información que tienes en la tabla, primero has un `SELECT elCodigo FROM tuTabla ORDER BY elCodigo DESC LIMIT 1` (supongo también puede servir `MAX`), desde PHP le quitas el `PR` con [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), conviertes ese valor a entero, le sumas `1`. Luego [rellenas con ceros](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php), le vuelves a añadir el `PR` y lo pones en el atributo `value="xxx"` del formulario. Le puedes agregar `readonly` para que el usuario no modifique el campo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo que ese campo sea interno (no modificable desde el formulario) y vaya asociado al autonumérico de la tabla `productos`, de hecho es que no necesitas ni guardarlo, pues podrías generarlo en cualquier momento simplemente con:

```
SELECT *,
  CONCAT('PR',LPAD(id_producto,4,'0')) `product-code`
  FROM productos;
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  producto varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO productos (producto) VALUES
  ('Producto1'),('Producto2');
```

Obtendrías algo así:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| id_producto | producto  | product-code |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|           1 | Producto1 | PR0001       |
|           2 | Producto2 | PR0002       |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Si necesitas que esos códigos sean consecutivos, échale un vistazo a esta otra pregunta que acabo de responder [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/617097).

Espero que esto resuelva tu situación. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias David. Me sirvió tu idea. Pero ahora me surge otra duda. A la hora de crear un producto he puesto el campo también readonly, porque cuando recojo los valores del formulario, lo he puesto así: ``$p_code=remove_junk($db->escape(CONCAT('PR',LPAD($_POST['product-id'],4,'0'))));`` Pero a la hora de crear un producto me dice que el id no puede estar en blanco, pues el codigo se crea a partir del id

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema aunque, al generar el código a partir de un autonumérico, éste se genera con cada inserción, no deberías tener que hacer nada más. Publica una nueva pregunta aportando la estructura de la tabla, unos datos de ejemplo, y una muestra de lo que pretendes hacer. Déjame aquí mismo el enlace.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/617264/llenar-campo-uniendo-un-texto-y-el-id-de-otro-campo

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla, @OCHOA ya te ha respondido a lo que yo también he entendido. Olvida el código y céntrate en el `id`. El código ya lo mostrarás cuando sea necesario para el usuario pero, internamente, no lo te hace falta.