# llenar campo uniendo un texto y el id de otro campo

Tags: php, html, mysql

En mi bbdd de phpmyadmin tengo una tabla productos con un id auto-increment y otra columna llamada code, que agregué más tarde, de tipo char de seis caracteres.
En la página product lo muestro así:

```
<td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($product['code']); ?></td>
```

En la página edit_product lo tengó así:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="product-code" value="<?php echo remove_junk($product['code']); ?>" readonly minlength="6" maxlength="6">
```

El problema está a la hora de crear el producto. Me gustaría que quedara así: PR0001. Es decir, las letras PR, tres o dos ceros según ocupe el id, que iría al final.
Probé a poner el concat, pero en php no se puede. Intenté con puntos, que en teoría sí deja, pero tampoco lo conseguí. Buscando por internet, encontré str_pad, pero no dio resultado. Hice pruebas y funcionaba bien:

```
echo str_pad("PR",6,"0").$id;
```

Pero hay dos problemas: a la hora de crear el code no se sabe todavía el id que va a contener. Y el campo no se puede quedar vacío al crear el producto. Además, cuando haya que quitar un cero por doble dígito del id, no sé cómo indicarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, la lógica la estas haciendo al revés.

El producto debe ser siempre accesible por su `ID`. Como lo quieras mostrar es algo diferente y para ello debes usar

```php
$id = 33;
echo $code = "PR".str_pad($id, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

// PR0033
// PR0631
// PR0003
```

Pero repito que esto debe ser a nivel visual, ni siquiera es necesario que lo guardes en la DB puesto que cuando quieras ver el producto con **ID 1**, por ejemplo, al momento de presentarlo lo pasas por la función que puse antes y el resultado sería **PR0001**.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al final, quité el campo de la bbdd y con tu linea de código lo muesto readonly en donde necesite.

Comment: Me alegra que te sirviera pero ojo con el **Readonly**, eso se puede desactivar, yo he hecho "cositas" en sitios que manejan así los datos. Mejor muéstralo en un Label y punto. Ya luego lo puedes mandar en un `input hidden` u otros métodos pero el  **Readonly** no es lo mejor.